# How to get the value from an array which has key/value pair objects?

Tags: javascript

In the below array, I have objects with key/value pairs

```
var options = [{
    key: "select",
    value: null
}, {
    key: "one",
    value: "First Option"
},
{
    key: "second",
    value: "Second Option"
}];
```

how to get the value based on  key from options array?

For example, if the key is "select" it should return null,
 if the key is "one" it should return "First Option".

Comment: @Jaromanda X Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

ES6 has the find-function for arrays:

```
var val = options.find(function(o){ return o.key==="select" }).value;
```

And maybe wrap it in a function of your own to make it a bit more reusable:

```
function findValue(arr, key){
  return arr.find(function(o){ return o.key===key }).value;
}

var val = findValue(options,"select");
```

I would argue this is the most semantically correct answer without modifying the original array, but you must have realized by now that there are many ways to skin this cat. (I like Zodiac Zubeda's answer because it's a simple for-loop so fast and backwards compatible and has the break that skips unnecessary iterations.)

Answer (score 3):

You can search for the object you want from the array, then get the value of that object:

```
var value;

// Loop through the options array
for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    // If the key for this iteration's element is desired
    if (options[i].key == "select") {
        // Set the value to appropriately and exit the loop
        value = options[i].value;
        break;
    }
}
```

This code makes "value" equal to the value you want, based on your key. If you want to determine the value multiple times, you can wrap the code in a function and return value. You'd probably also want to add a parameter for the desired key, and replace `options[i].key == "select"` with `"options[i].key == <parameter name>"`.

Alternatively, you can structure your objects like so:

```
var options = {
    "select": null,
    "one": "First Option",
    "second": "Second Option"
};
```

With this, you can access the value of a desired key like so:

```
options[<desired key>]
```

So, `options["select"]` would return `null`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer and suggestions, in my case it is a json data

Comment: Ah, well I'm glad I was able to provide helpful information. Good luck on your project!

Answer (score 2):

Using [Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) (modern browsers and IE9+):

```
options.filter(function(opt) {
  return opt.key === 'one';
})[0].value;
```

Or a one-liner using ES6 arrow notation:

```
options.filter(opt => opt.key === 'one')[0].value;
```

Reusable function, returning `null` if a match is not found:

```
function findValueByKey(opts, key) {
  var match = opts.filter(function(opt) {
    return opt.key === key;
  });
  return match[0] ? match[0].value : null;
}
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/02oawajt/3/

Comment: This will raise an error if no option item is found

Answer (score 1):

You have to brute force it...

```
function findValueForOption(key) {
    for (i = 0; i < options.length; i++) { 
        if (options[i].key === key) {
            return options[i].value;
        }
    }
    return null;  // Or do whatever you feel is appropriate when an unspecified key is requested...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

[Arraymap](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_map.asp) use to find `key` and `value`

```js
var options = [{
    key: "select",
    value: null
}, {
    key: "one",
    value: "First Option"
},
{
    key: "second",
    value: "Second Option"
}];



var run = options.map(function (item,index) {
    var fullname = 'the key='+item.key+',and value='+item.value;
    return fullname;
})
console.log(run);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
var options = [{
  key: "select",
  value: null
}, {
  key: "one",
  value: "First Option"
}, {
  key: "second",
  value: "Second Option"
}];

// output values of whatever you like
checkValue("select");
console.log("------------------------------");
checkValue("one");
console.log("------------------------------");
checkValue("second");
console.log("------------------------------");

function checkValue(val) {
  for (var i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
    
    if(options[i].key == val){
        console.log("VALUE IS: " + options[i].value);
    }
    
  }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `forEach` to loop through he json..

There are multiple ways of doing it.

This is one of the way

```
var options = [{
        key: "select",
        value: null
    }, {
        key: "one",
        value: "First Option"
    },
    {
        key: "second",
        value: "Second Option"
    }];
    options.forEach(function(item){
    console.log(item.value)

    })
```

[**DEMO**](https://jsfiddle.net/v1acnq12/)

Answer (score 0):

You may want to consider restructuring your data. It appears you took key, value literally:

If you structure your data like this:

```
var options = [
  {
   select: null
  },
  {
   one: 'first option'
  }
];
```

You can just call options.select to retrieve the value.

Comment: This JSON is more readable and easier to traverse, yes, but perhaps he's getting it from an API (or something else he can't change).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind the dependency, you can turn your array into a proper Object using Lodash [`_.fromPairs`](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.0#fromPairs):

```
pairs = options.map(o => [o.key, o.value])
// [["select", null], ["one", "First"], ["two", "Second"]]

_.fromPairs(pairs)
// { select: null, one: "First", second: "Second" }
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope  this will work for you

```
function getValue(keyName) {

   if(!keyName) return ''

  var value = _.find(options, function(obj){
      if(obj.key === keyName) {
          return true
      }
  })

  if(value === undefined) return ''

  return value.value
}

var a = getValue('one')
```

Check snippet for working example.

```js
$(function(){
    var options = [{
      key: "select",
      value: null
    }, {
      key: "one",
      value: "First Option"
    },
    {
      key: "second",
      value: "Second Option"
    }];
  
    function getValue(keyName) {
   
       if(!keyName) return ''

      var value = _.find(options, function(obj){
          if(obj.key === keyName) {
              return true
          }
      })
    
      if(value === undefined) return ''
    
      return value.value
    }
  
    var a = getValue('one')
    console.log(a)
  })
```

```html
<script src="http://underscorejs.org/underscore.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For older/ES3 environments:

```
function find(arr, key) {
    for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i += 1) {
        if (arr[i].key === key) {
            return arr[i].value;
        }
    }
}
```

For newer/ES5 environments:

```
function find(arr, key) {
    return (arr.filter(function(item) { return item.key === key})[0] || {}).value;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is one way of doing it. I have changed the structure of it like other suggested through program and then access the new Structure.

```
var options = [{
    key: "select",
    value: null
}, {
    key: "one",
    value: "First Option"
},
{
    key: "second",
    value: "Second Option"
}];

function changeStructure(obj){
    var newObj = {};
  obj.forEach(function(val, index){
            newObj[val['key']] =  val['value'];
  });
  return newObj;
}

var newStructure = changeStructure(options);
```

New Structure :

```
 {
      one : "First Option"
      second:"Second Option"
      select:null
}
```

Now you can access it using key:

```
console.log(newStructure['select']); or console.log(newStructure.select)
```

[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p4yyzpcw/)

Answer (score -1):

You can use `for..of` loop.

```js
var options = [{
  key: "select",
  value: null
}, {
  key: "one",
  value: "First Option"
}, {
  key: "second",
  value: "Second Option"
}];

let filter = (array, prop, res = void 0) => {
  for (let {key, value} of array) prop === key && (res = value); return res
}

console.log(filter(options, "select"));
console.log(filter(options, "one"));
console.log(filter(options, "second"));
```